# Choose Date from Webpage calendar popup using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to choose date from Webpage calendar and apply the filter there after. The date to be set will be in excl sheet cell. The format of the date is like "10 Sep 2018". 
Below is the html DOM for the site I am looking at. Please help:

```
<div class="datepicker__header"><a class="datepicker__navigation datepicker__navigation--previous">
</a><span class="datepicker__current-month">June 2018</span>
<a class="datepicker__navigation datepicker__navigation--next"></a>

<div class="weekday-container"><div class="datepicker__week-day">Mo</div><div class="datepicker__week-day">Tu</div><div class="datepicker__week-day">We</div>

<div class="datepicker__week-day">Th</div>

<div class="datepicker__week-day">Fr</div><div class="datepicker__week-day">Sa</div>
<div class="datepicker__week-day">Su</div></div></div>

<div class="datepicker__month"><div><div class="datepicker__day">28</div><div class="datepicker__day">29</div><div class="datepicker__day">30</div><div class="datepicker__day">31</div><div class="datepicker__day">1</div><div class="datepicker__day">2</div><div class="datepicker__day">3</div></div><div><div class="datepicker__day">4</div><div class="datepicker__day">5</div><div class="datepicker__day">6</div><div class="datepicker__day">7</div><div class="datepicker__day">8</div><div class="datepicker__day">9</div><div class="datepicker__day">10</div></div><div><div class="datepicker__day">11</div><div class="datepicker__day">12</div><div class="datepicker__day">13</div><div class="datepicker__day">14</div><div class="datepicker__day">15</div><div class="datepicker__day">16</div><div class="datepicker__day">17</div></div><div><div class="datepicker__day">18</div><div class="datepicker__day">19</div><div class="datepicker__day">20</div><div class="datepicker__day">21</div><div class="datepicker__day">22</div><div class="datepicker__day">23</div><div class="datepicker__day">24</div></div><div><div class="datepicker__day datepicker__day--selected">25</div><div class="datepicker__day">26</div><div class="datepicker__day">27</div><div class="datepicker__day">28</div><div class="datepicker__day">29</div><div class="datepicker__day">30</div><div class="datepicker__day">1</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). Because this is no free code writing service you will need to show what you have tried so far. Also it is absolutely necessary that you ask a question. You didn't ask one yet.

Comment: Share what you have tried, clarify the question and please include the URL if possible. And that is not the DOM. It is a small HTML extract - if you can include the entire HTMLDocument using https://pastebin.com/ that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an attempt like this: it works if the pop up also allows you to type to scroll the pop up list, but it may not in case it is a true pop-up-only choice. The month choice seems to be a "type" choice, instead the day seems to be a true pop-up (anyway I do not see the year field here). So, try to use something like this, please adapt it to your specific code needs

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim aNodeList, bNodeList As Object, cc,vv As Long

with IE
  Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("div[class=datepicker__month]")        
  For cc = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
      aNodeList.Item(cc).Value="Sep"
  Next cc

  Set bNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("div[class=datepicker__day]")        
  For vv = 0 To bNodeList.Length - 1
        bNodeList.Item(vv).Value=10
  Next vv
End With
```

Or, as an alternative (try the one that works best for that specific page!):

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim aNodeList, bNodeList As Object, cc,vv As Long

With IE
  Set aNodeList = .document.getElementsByTagName("div")

  For Each element In aNodeList

      If element.class = "datepicker__day" Then
           element.Value=10
      End if

      If element.class = "datepicker__month" Then
           element.Value="Sep"
      End if
  Next

End With
```